# Cannot deserialize enum value with post request

Tags: micronaut

Suppose I have an enum class:

```
    enum class Foo(val type: String) {
        DEFAULT("default"),
        OTHER("other")
    }
```

And a get request:

```
    @field:QueryValue("foo", defaultValue = "DEFAULT")
    @field:Nullable
    var foo: Foo = Foo.DEFAULT
```

This will properly serialize a parameter passed in as `foo: default` or `foo: other`

However, for a post request:

```
    @Body
    @field:Nullable
    var foo: Foo = Foo.DEFAULT
```

If I post a json body of `{ "foo": "default" }` or `{ "foo": "other" }`

I will get an error:

```
Failed to convert argument [p0] for value [null] due to: Cannot deserialize value of type `Foo` from String \"default\": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [DEFAULT, OTHER]\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] ...
```

Any help would be appreciated here! I'm not really sure if this is intended or would be considered a bug. On a side note, is there an annotation that would be able to capitalize the field instead? (since `foo: DEFAULT` or `foo: OTHER` are valid)

Answer (score 2):

This post here details how to get around this issue:
https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1830

Quote:

```
Adding to src/main/resources/application.yml

jackson:
  mapper:
    ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS: true

makes both test pass.
```